# XRDP and dynamic screen resolution

Tags: rdp

I need to connect remotely from a Windows machine to an EXISTING session on a Linux machine. I'm currently using XRDP on the Linux server and mstsc (native RDP client) on the Windows client. The problem is that the session does not resize to match the  resolution of the monitor on the client side.

When the server is also Windows, this works flawlessly, automatically adjusting not only the screen resolution, but also the number of monitors.
Is there a way to setup XRDP on Linux to support this feature?